# Pandas dataframe applying NA to part of the data

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, type-conversion

Let me preface this with I am new at using pandas so I'm sorry if this question is basic or answered before, I looked online and couldn't find what I needed.

I have a dataframe that consists of a baseball teams schedule.  Some of the games have been played already and as a result the results from the game are inputed in the dataframe.  However, for games that are yet to happen, there is only the time they are to be played (eg 1:35 pm).

So, I would like to convert all of the values of the games yet to happen into Na's.

Thank you

As requested here is what the results dataframe for the Arizona Diamondbacks contains

```
print MLB['ARI']
0     0
1     0
2     0
3     1
4     0
5     0
6     0
7     0
8     1
9     0
10    1
...
151    3:40 pm
152    8:40 pm
153    8:10 pm
154    4:10 pm
155    4:10 pm
156    8:10 pm
157    8:10 pm
158    1:10 pm
159    9:40 pm
160    8:10 pm
161    4:10 pm
Name: ARI, Length: 162, dtype: object
```

Comment: Can you post some example records?

Comment: @LiamFoley print MLB['ARI']
0     0
1     0
2     0
3     1
4     0
5     0
6     0
7     0
8     1
9     0
10    1
11    1
12    0
13    0
14    0
...
147    8:10 pm
148    4:10 pm
149    9:40 pm
150    9:40 pm
151    3:40 pm
152    8:40 pm
153    8:10 pm
154    4:10 pm
155    4:10 pm
156    8:10 pm
157    8:10 pm
158    1:10 pm
159    9:40 pm
160    8:10 pm
161    4:10 pm
Name: ARI, Length: 162, dtype: objecty, z))

Comment: How do I post it formated properly, it isn't letting me use enter

Comment: You need to indent each line of code 4 spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't figure out any direct solution, only iterative

```
for i in xrange(len(MLB)):
    if 'pm' in MLB.['ARI'].iat[i] or 'am' in MLB.['ARI'].iat[i]:
        MLB.['ARI'].iat[i] = np.nan
```

This should work if your actual values (1s and 0s) are also strings. If they are numbers, try:

```
for i in xrange(len(MLB)):
    if type(MLB.['ARI'].iat[i]) != type(1):
        MLB.['ARI'].iat[i] = np.nan
```

Comment: There was an error:  File "<ipython-input-36-6d4527773762>", line 1
    MLB['ARI'].contains('pm') = np.nan
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call

Comment: MLB[MLB['ARI']].contains('pm') = np.nan

Comment: You need to preface the `contains` with a `str` to access the string methods, i.e.,  `df['result'].str.contains`.  Also, you need to use `|` instead of `or` when comparing series/ndarrays.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't test it before.

Comment: @Inox Thanks, it worked.  The only thing I would say, is that your syntax is slightly wrong, you need to remove the 2 instances of a period between MLB.['ARI']

Comment: Yep, it's kind of hard to get the indentation right here, as TAB moves from the textbox to a button, so I put some spaces. Usually not work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

The more idiomatic way to do this would be with the vectorised string methods.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#vectorized-string-methods

```
mask = MLB['ARI'].str.contains('pm') #create boolean array
MLB['ARI'][mask] = np.nan #the column names goes first
```

Create the boolean array from and then use it to select the data you want.
Make sure that the column name goes before the masking array, otherwise you'll be acting on a copy of the data and your original dataframe wont get updated.

```
MLB['ARI'][mask] #returns a view on MLB datafrmae, will be updated
MLB[mask]['ARI'] #returns a copy of MLB, wont be updated.
```